# ES: Sort by date field requires to enable fielddata

Tags: php, laravel, elasticsearch

I am attempting to get all hits of an index sorted by the `updated_at` field.

However, that fails with the following message:

`"{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on [updated_at] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting the inverted index.`

This is the mapping that I am using:

```
Map::create($this->getModelType(), function (Blueprint $map) {
            $map->integer('id');
            $map->addField('text', 'title');
            $map->date('created_at')->format('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');
            $map->date('updated_at')->format('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');
            $map->date('deleted_at')->format('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');
}));
```

and this is the code to get all the data sorted by the `updated_at` field:

```
 $titleData = $this->title->search()->sortBy('updated_at', 'DESC');
```

Any ideas?

Comment: what type has `updated_at` field? it's `date` or `text`?

Comment: It's a `date` field but now I have got it working like this: $this->title->search()->sortBy('updated_at', 'DESC')->size(100)->get()->hits();

Comment: You are doing it wrong . If it is showing this error then you must check you mapping of the index . created_at , updated_at might be text fields

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @gaurav9620! Having a look what can be improved.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like in `ElasticSearch` index `updated_at` is stored as [text](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/text.html). Text fields are analyzed and normally `ElasticSearch` cannot sort by those fields, because [fielddata is disabled on text fields by default](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/fielddata.html).

In order to overcome it you can create [mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html) with [keyword](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/keyword.html) type. It might look like this:

```
"updated_at": {
  "type": "text", // assuming you originally have it as text
  "fields": {
    "original": "keyword",
    "ignore_above": 64 // You can skip or change it and ES applies default value. 
  }
}
```

And then you should use mapping for sorting. You can access it like this: `updated_at.original`.

Comment: Thanks, @rkm. Will give it a go and come back to this thread.

Comment: So, there is a bug in the package that I'm using that although having declared it as  a date field it doesn't treat it so. Adding the `fielddata=true` attribute resolved the issue.

Comment: @thitami It's a bad workaround as it is extremely expensive and will probably kill a big system.